# MongoDB Do I need to worry about Collection Collation strength performance issues?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, collation

I apologize if my title is not the best but I had a hard time describing my question. I'm interested to know what the downsides would be in setting the collation of a collection to strength = 2. It is my understanding this allows me to query the document in a case-insensitive way. I'm used to this coming from a SQL background and was surprised when this wasn't the default. I know you set specific field index collations but if you create a collection like so:

```
db.createCollection('myColl',{locale:'en',strength:2});
```

Then any string field I query will be case-insensitive. In my opinion this is great for most of my use cases but I'm wondering does creating this collation on most of my collections cause more processing load when it is performing queries?

Is the best practice to create collections with case-sensitive collation and then only add collation on specific fields? My gut tells me that the developers of MongoDb have a good reason to not have case-insensitive collation to be default on collections and I don't want to do something that inadvertently will cause more load on a server if unneeded. Now another reason for not setting case-insensitive collation could be because they need to know the 'locale' in order to set it. So maybe that could be the reason and not because it would cause more processing time.

I hope this question makes sense. I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Apart from case insensitivity, are your queries on string values otherwise exact matches?

Comment: no, I need to handle partial word matches. meaning if I search for 'john' it will return 'Johnathon' etc. I'm told $text searches do not allow this and require a specific type of index to work.